# Can you define multiple definitions inside a single defs tag in SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it OK to use multiple definitions inside a *single* def tag at the root of the document?

Example. Notice all of the gradients ***inside*** the ***defs*** tag.

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg width="0" height="0">
       <defs>
         <linearGradient id="Gradient01">
           <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#39F" />
           <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#F3F" />
         </linearGradient>
         <linearGradient id="Gradient02">
           <stop offset="00%" stop-color="#3F3" />
           <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#39F" />
           <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#F55" />
         </linearGradient>
       </defs>
    </svg>
    <svg width="800px" height="300px"
           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

        <rect x="10" y="10" width="200" height="20" 
              fill="url(#Gradient01)" />
        <svg width="380px" height="330px"      
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

        <rect x="10" y="50" width="200" height="20" 
              fill="url(#Gradient02)" />
        </svg>
      </svg>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `def` tag. There is a `defs` tag. This should be a hint :)

But for a formal answer, look how `defs` is [defined](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#DefsElement):

> **Content model:** Any number of the following elements, in any order: ...

Comment: It says, "Any number of paint server elements — ‘linearGradient’, ‘radialGradient’, ‘pattern’". That works.